# Plymouth on Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspbian, boot, packages

Has anyone got `plymouth` (startup logo package) working on Raspberry Pi?

On Raspbian Wheezy, I've successfully installed plymouth using `apt-get` but when I go to create the required initramfs, I get this:

```
# sudo update-initramfs -c -k `uname -r`
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.12.34+
cp: cannot stat `/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/pango/1.6.0/module-files.d/libpango1.0-0.modules': No such file or directory
E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/plymouth failed with return 1.
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-3.12.34+ with 1.
```

I've checked the filesystem and the entire `pango` directory is not present.

I've checked Google and most hits on that error refer to the directory moving from `/usr/lib/pango` to `/usr/lib/*arch*/pango`, which is not the problem here (I checked both places).

I've checked the Debian repository (via their web interface) and they claim that these files are part of the package [libpango1.0-0](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/armhf/libpango1.0-0/filelist).  I do have the Raspbian version of that package installed, but according to `dpkg -L` it only contains the documentation files, not the libraries.

Is this a Raspbian packaging error, or has this been intentionally split to some other package (I couldn't find anything likely-sounding), or am I missing something else?

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to edit
`/usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/plymouth`
and comment out anything referring to pango

Comment: Yes, it really works this way. Some more details can be seen from the bug description at launchpad, linked in a comment by Miral to the answer by goldilocks.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I got it to work on my Pi 2 using the latest raspbian (with thanks to [jeg](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/27031/27066) and [david](https://github.com/notro/fbtft/wiki/Bootsplash))

1. Edit plymouth, search for "pango" and comment out every line that refers to it. (there's a whole if block to knock out)

   ```
   sudo nano /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/plymouth
   ```
2. Install plymouth framebuffer support

   ```
   sudo apt-get install plymouth-drm
   ```
3. Make initramfs image

   ```
   sudo update-initramfs -c -k $(uname -r)
   ```
4. Tell the bootloader to use the generated image

   ```
   sudo nano /boot/config.txt
   ```

   and add a line containing

   ```
   initramfs initrd.img-X.XX.XX+
   ```

   replacing the x's with the output of

   ```
   uname -r
   ```
5. Specify some additional modules to be loaded

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/initramfs-tools/modules
   ```

   and add these modules:

   ```
   fbtft
   fbtft_device name=hy28a verbose=0
   fb_ili9320
   ```
6. Tell plymouth to use /dev/fb1

   ```
   echo "export FRAMEBUFFER=/dev/fb1" | sudo tee /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/fb1
   ```
7. Set theme

   ```
   sudo plymouth-set-default-theme text
   ```
8. Update initramfs

   ```
   sudo update-initramfs -u
   ```
9. Add some options to boot command line

   ```
   sudo nano /boot/cmdline.txt
   ```

   and at the end of the line add this

   ```
   fbcon=map:10 splash quiet plymouth.ignore-serial-consoles
   ```
10. Reboot

This worked for me (although text and details) are the only themes that seem to work. **If it you break your pi following this step by step you get to keep both pieces.**

Comment: Thanks for the instructions which were very helpful to get me started, but this only worked for me when I used the 'text' and 'detail' themes. After a lot of searching and experimenting I finally decided that, at least in my case using a RPi2 and Raspbian, the error was in step 6. My RPi2 did not have a /dev/fb1 device after boot. So I figured it might not have one during startup either and was falling back to the text or detail themes. So I replaced step 6 with: echo "export FRAMEBUFFER=/dev/fb0" | sudo tee /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/fb0 using fb0 instead and this did the trick for me.

Comment: @Leo thanks for your input. When I have some time I'll check it out and then will update this post.

Comment: Trying this under the current Raspian Jessie, the install of plymouth-drm fails: plymouth-drm : Depends: plymouth (= 0.8.5.1-5) I suppose because the installed plymouth is 0.9.0-9 . Any ideas?

Comment: I also found that fb0 is the way to get this working. Also step 5 appears to be unnecessary (works fine for me on a B+ without it). Note that there's really no need to create the ramfs then update it; you can just run the `-c -k "$(uname -r)"` version instead of step 8, then you don't need to run step 3 at all. Also once you've run through the setup once, themes can be swapped out by running `sudo plymouth-set-default-theme -R <name>`, which invokes `update-initramfs -u` automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Something interesting in output from `apt-cache search libpango | grep ^libpango`:

```
libpango-1.0-0 - Layout and rendering of internationalized text
libpango1.0-0 - Layout and rendering of internationalized text
```

I don't have them installed so can't see a list of files; `apt-cache showpkg` on the them shows different sets of details, but trying to `apt-get install` them looks exactly the same.

However:

```
> apt-file search "libpango1.0-0.modules"
libpango1.0-0: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/pango/1.6.0/module-files.d/libpango1.0-0.modules
```

That's exactly the file you are looking for, supposedly in the package you already have installed.  I downloaded both packages with `apt-get download` to see what was in them, and indeed, `libpango1.0-0` doesn't contain anything except trivial documentation.  `libpango-1.0-0` contains exactly the same thing *plus the actual library*, but it does not contain that `module-files.d` directory.

Seems like a bug at least in the sense that `apt-file search` reports wrongly.  I did not find any reports in debian proper or raspbian for this, but I think you should file one:

http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs

You have to create a "ubuntu one" account in the process.

Comment: Ok, filed as https://bugs.launchpad.net/raspbian/+bug/1401005.  I guess we'll see what happens. :)

Comment: In the bug you filed you said you had to fiddle with init scripts. Care to share how you managed to get it working?

Comment: @sberder: sorry, I missed your question.  The main thing was to add `plymouth --quit --wait || true` into `/etc/init.d/nodm` just prior to actually starting nodm.  Unfortunately this is not entirely satisfactory as after this change issuing `service nodm restart` after startup when plymouth is no longer running causes it to hang.  Removing the `--wait` flag should resolve this but IIRC it caused another issue, though I don't recall what it was at the moment.

Comment: Note that there is a script `/etc/init.d/plymouth` that is supposed to get plymouth to quit but since it depends on `$all` it runs last, after the `nodm` script, and that appears to be a problem for that (presumably it works fine with `gdm` etc).  In my case I commented out the `plymouth --quit` that was in this script as well (since I had added it to the `nodm` script), but it should be harmless if left there.

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution that seems to work (tried it with the joy theme).

Before running `sudo update-initramfs -u`, download the pango package from the official Debian repository:

```
wget http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/pool/main/p/pango1.0/libpango1.0-0_1.30.0-1_armhf.deb
```

Then extract the package somewhere convenient, i.e `/home/pi/pango`:

```
dpkg --extract libpango1.0-0_1.30.0-1_armhf.deb /home/pi/pango
```

Then make the pango directory in `/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/`:

```
sudo mkdir /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/pango
```

Now copy the contents of the pango directory from `/home/pi/pango/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/' to the directory you just created:

```
sudo cp -r /home/pi/pango/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/pango/* /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/pango/
```

Now `sudo update-initramfs -u` should work - it did for me.

I have also made a script that can be downloaded that does this on Github: https://gist.github.com/alanpullen/cdfeb71bd6d85edabf87[1](https://gist.github.com/alanpullen/cdfeb71bd6d85edabf87)

This can also be downloaded and run using the following commands:

```
wget https://gist.githubusercontent.com/alanpullen/cdfeb71bd6d85edabf87/raw/5f44e180191e5b02ae8882743db2b8f1a04f9892/plymouth-pango-fix.sh
chmod +x plymouth-pango-fix.sh
./plymouth-pango-fix.sh
```