# Plymouth terminates too early

Tags: boot

I set up plymouth to run on my Raspberry Pi 3 using the answer provided by tcyrus on this page: [Plymouth on Raspberry Pi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/24900/plymouth-on-raspberry-pi)
Now the bootscreen comes up when I shut down or start the Pi, but on boot it quits way too early. I see the animation for around 3 seconds, then I see a black screen for around 10 seconds until I see the desktop. I have already tried editing the plymouth-quit and plymouth-quit-wait services to launch them afer raspi-config (this is the service that gets launched right before x11-common), without any change. I also tried the patch provided here:
https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/systemd-devel/2010-September/000323.html, as well as changing the service to run after various other services, which again didn't have any effecton the animation duration.

Is there any way to make plymouth terminate only when the Pi already booted?